# Android Content Provider - Using Query Method To Insert, Delete, and Update

Tags: android, android-contentprovider

I have been studying Content Providers by reading [Android Developer Fundamentals (Version 1)](https://google-developer-training.github.io/android-developer-fundamentals-course-concepts/en/Unit%204/111_c_share_data_through_content_providers.html).

Under section "11.1 Share Data Through Content Providers" / "The query() method" there is a note that states

> Note: The insert, delete, and update methods are provided for
>   convenience and clarity. Technically, the query method could handle
>   all requests, including those to insert, delete, and update data.

How can query method be used to insert / delete / and update data? The query method has the following signature and does not take in custom SQL strings.

```
public Cursor query(Uri uri, String[] projection, String selection,String[] selectionArgs, String sortOrder){}
```

I have not been able to find any resources that shows how this can be done. All seems to utilize the provided methods.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Frankly, that is a really poor job in that training guide. All it will do is confuse people.

I presume what they mean is that there is nothing magic about `query()` that forces it to only perform SQL `SELECT` statements. A `ContentProvider` is a facade — you can use it to store and retrieve from pretty much whatever you want, not just SQLite.

So, you could have your `query()` method:

- Examine the `Uri`
- Look for it to be of the form `content://your.authority/something/insert/put/data/here`
- Parse the `Uri` to get the `put`, `data`, and `here` values
- Insert those in a table under some pre-determined columns
- Return an empty `MatrixCursor`

Or, it could:

- Examine the `Uri`
- Look for it to be of the form `content://your.authority/something/insert`
- Insert a row using the `projection` for the columns and the `selectionArgs` as the values to put in those columns
- Return an empty `MatrixCursor`

I do not know why anyone would do that, but it is certainly possible.

Comment: Yes, I agree it is not an ideal way of using query method. The frustration was to understand how it can be done, rather than whether it should be done. Thank you.